# Adding a second extruder to reprap

Tags: arduino

Not sure if this is the place where this belongs but...

I'm working on adding a second extruder head to the rep rap i have that uses RAMPS Electronics.
http://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS

I'm trying to assign a bit to the arduino mega that regulates with extruder were using. 1 for tool 1 and 0 for tool 2. any one know how I could do this or is anyone able to at least point me to someone who might?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to find the code for the Arduino mega sketch that you are using, figure out which stepper driver is controlling extruder tool 1 and then find in the sketch where it is being activated. Insert an if statement at that point in the code at that point that checks if an IO pin on the Arduino is set. If it is set, actuate extruder tool 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is really much of an answer, but I know the guys over at [N-bit Wonder](http://nbitwonder.com) have been posting a lot about their "Rep-Rap Saga"... they might be able to help if you reached out to them. Their "RepRap Saga series" starts out [here](http://nbitwonder.com/blog/2011/07/18/reprap-mendel-prologue/). George is up to Part 9 of the series at the time of this post. Best of luck, feel free to post back to answer your own question.